# Add two integers to each element of a list in a for loop

Tags: r, list, for-loop

please do let me know if this question is too general.

I'm trying to implement a for loop with a nested for loop. Every time the for loop runs, it will either `print` two integer values or `next` onto the next iteration.

As a result, I have outputs
 from the for loop that looks like this:

```
[1] 10 57
[1] 10 58
[1] 10 59
[1] 10 63
[1] 10 64
[1] 10 67
[1] 10 68
[1] 10 69
[1] 10 70
[1] 10 71
[1] 10 72
[1] 10 75
[1] 10 76
[1] 10 77
[1] 10 78
[1] 10 79
[1] 10 80
[1] 10 82
[1] 10 86
[1] 10 87
[1] 10 90
```

I was wondering what are best practices for inserting thse pairs of integers in lists. Since there is a for loop with an iterator of `i` nested inside a for loop with an iterator of `j`, I can not just write:

`list[[i]] <- c(i, j)`

Comment: Could you include your for-loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say `indx` is a vector with some random values:

```
[1] 58 61 67 69 70 72 78 79 84 85
```

The for loop I would write:

```
for(i in 1:3){
  for(j in indx){
    print(c(i, j))
  }
}
```

Would produce the following output (without assigning it to an object):

```
[1]  1 58
[1]  1 61
[1]  1 67
[1]  1 69
[1]  1 70
[1]  1 72
[1]  1 78
[1]  1 79
[1]  1 84
[1]  1 85
[1]  2 58
[1]  2 61
...
[1]  3 84
[1]  3 85
```

If you're trying to save it into a vector, this code works for you:

```
myls <- vector()
for(i in 1:3){
  for(j in indx){
      myls <- c(myls, c(i, j))
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
Based on OP's additional comment, I wanted to show you another way to directly get a list, by appending each combination of `i` and `j` as a list element:

```
indx <- c(58, 61, 67, 69, 70, 72, 78, 79, 84, 85)
myls <- list()
for(i in 1:3){
  for(j in indx){
      myls <- c(myls, list(c(i, j)))
  }
}
```

Your `myls` variable is now a list:

```
myls[1:3]

[[1]]
[1]  1 58

[[2]]
[1]  1 61

[[3]]
[1]  1 67
```

Comment: When I run `as.list()` R puts each number into one element. Do you know a way to put pairs of numbers (1 58) (1 61) etc into each element of a list?

Comment: See the updated edit - `myls` is now a list, without having to use do explicit coercion; I think this more directly gets you the desired output. Hope this helps!